# Change <p> text to jumpMenu text

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm trying to change the text of my `<p>` tag to the text of the `<option>` from my jumpMenu once the option is selected. Also, I am trying to change the thumbnail of my image above the `<p>` that corresponds with the `<option>`. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we can go from there.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. So far I only have my image, `<p>` and jumpMenu. I don't even know where to begin with this.

Comment: The way you're casing that name, I assume its a library.  How far off am I?

Comment: jumpMenu? It's a simple drop down menu titled "jumpMenu" in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use onChange event of select :

**First give the id of p :**

```
<p id="idp"></p> 

function change(v){

      if(v=="yourvalue"){
           $('#idp').html("yor html content like a your text and image");
        }
}
```

call this function on onChange(this.value) event